# Picklist values different in UI From database

Tags: picklist, customsetting, dependent-picklist

I can see different values for picklist field. Let say i have a field on Custom object Country__c which stores values like FR, CN, IN, US but in record new page or detail page i can see France, China, India, United States. How they are logically linked ? 
any help would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: Picklist values have label and API name. Label is displayed in front-end and api value is stored in back-end.

Comment: label and API are same like CN (Label) and CN(API). Finally i found solution, i checked for translations and there for CN picklist value its defined as China. @SaumyaRanjanSatapathy

Comment: Cool. I verified it now just now. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Picklist data might have been mapped to standardized picklist values.

There is a standard picklist given in salesforce for Country and state.

**From Setup > Data Management > State and Country/Territory Picklists**